# Непонятное поведение sqlalchemy.func.date

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy

имею такую орм модель

```
class Post(Base):
    added = Column(DateTime(timezone=t_zone), default=datetime.now)
    index = Column(Integer, default=0)
    ...
```

Имея `t_zone`

```
t_offset = timedelta(hours=3)
t_zone = timezone(offset=t_offset, name="UTC")
```

и такие записи в БД (`postgres`)

[image: БД]

Делая такой запрос

```
now = datetime.datetime.now(t_zone)
session.query(Post).filter(func.date(Post.added) == now.date()).order_by(Post.index.desc()).first()
```

Я, казалось бы, логично, получу запись `id=151`, потому что сегодня 10е число.

**НО НЕТ**, я получу запись `id=150`.

Почему? Ведь сегодня, очевидно, 10е число. Часовые пояса одинаковые для `now` и `post.added`, даже пайчарм говорит об этом.

Если у записи `id=150` изменить час с 23 на, например, 15, то всё правильно сработает и я не получу вчерашнюю запись

**P.S.**

Я заметил, что в БД поле `added` является `timestamp without time zone`, хотя в орм я явно указываю тайм зону. Миграции проводил, даже таблицы пересоздавал, всё так же

**P.S.2**

Поделал запросы через интерактив. Типом данных у `added`, как говорит мне `DataGrip`, является `timestamp with time zone`

[image: вывод]

Comment: Интересно, там дата указана с часовым поясом? И какая дата будет если вывести в питоне `added` для id=150

Comment: А тип данных для поля added у вас какой? `timestamp` или `timestamptz`?